# PHP / Eloquent - Iterate through collection and set variable not in scope

Tags: php, arrays, function, eloquent, each

I'm very new to Eloquent I've spent hours searching and I can't find an exact solution to my problem.

I have the following model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class Answer extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_answers';

    protected $fillable = [
       'method',
       'thoughts',
       'location'
    ];

    public function getMethodsStats()
    {
        $methods = Answer::selectRaw('*, count(*) AS method_count')- >groupBy('method');
    return $methods;
    }
}
```

In my controller, I try to iterate through the results to just echo the results to screen.
This works:

```
$methods = $app->answer->getMethodsStats();

$methods->each(function($method, $key)
{
    echo " --- Method: " . $method->method . " - " . $method->method_count;
});
```

The output is as expected:

> -- Method: fold - 3 --- Method: crumple - 2

To make things easier, I want to populate an array with these values. This array should be accessible outside the 'each' function once it's done.

The code:

```
$methods = $app->answer->getMethodsStats();
$stats = new array();

$methods->each(function($method, $key) use ($stats)
{

    $stats[$method->method] = $method->method_count;
});

echo json_encode($stats);
```

This doesn't work as I intended. I simply get an empty array.

Output:

> []

I know I'm missing something basic but 'what' that is I don't know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, PHP passes function arguments by value. You are passing **a copy** of `$stats`to your function. You need to pass it by reference instead, so that the function can modify it. Do this by appending an `&` before the variable, like this:

```
$methods->each(function($method, $key) use (&$stats) { ... }); 
 echo json_encode($stats);
```

Worth checking out:

- [PHP - passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)
- [PHP - function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

Comment: You, my friend, are an absolute star! thanks for this. Solved my problem immediately (and I learned something from it!)

Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! @Techedemic. Actually, I learnt something new too.

Answer (score 0):

try printing your mysql query first using `->toSql()`

like

```
    echo $methods = Answer::selectRaw('*, count(*) AS method_count')- >groupBy('method')->toSql();

die(); 
and check if you are getting the correct query to execute.
```

then after try to 
change

```
$methods = Answer::selectRaw('*, count(*) AS method_count')- >groupBy('method');
    return $methods;
```

to

```
 $methods = Answer::select(DB::Raw('*'), DB::Raw('count(*) AS method_count)')->groupBy('method');
    return $methods;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think the issue is in my query. The query works fine (as per my first example where I echo out the results and get what I expect).

My actual problem lies in variable scoping when I do the 'each' function...but I'm not sure where